# Delete same column nr across all active worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete a dynamic range of columns based on values in a range of cells that will differ from time to time, across multiple sheets. The values will be the headings of each column and the column numbers will be the same across all the worksheets, which it makes a little easier. Also, the sheets will be all worksheets, not just a select few. I've now tried various options like arrays to loops and just cannot get it to delete the columns in the rest of the sheets.

Below is the piece of code that I have now, and finally gave up on. As is, it deletes the columns correctly on the first sheet then I get an Object required error on the line noted below. Further below is a snapshot of the main sheet where the variables are listed.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim VarArr As Variant
    Dim u As Range
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim TestRng As Range
    Dim TestSht As Variant
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim a As Long
    
    a = Range("M1").Value
    b = 1
    
    VarArr = Array(Range(Cells(1, 14), Cells(1, 14 + a - 1)))
    Set TestRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10))
    For Each Cel In TestRng
        If IsError(Application.Match(Cel.Value, VarArr, 0)) Then
            If Not u Is Nothing Then
              Set u = Union(u, Cel)
            Else
              Set u = Cel
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not u Is Nothing Then
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        u.EntireColumn.Delete 'Object required error here
    Next ws
    
    End If
    
    End Sub
```

[snapshot of the variables used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmnN2.png)
Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use `Address` property of `Range` object

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Range(u.Address).EntireColumn.Delete 
Next ws
```

explanation:

`u` is pointing to a given `Range` in a given sheet (the currently active sheet when you launch the macro)

at the first `For Each ws In Worksheets` iteration, that range is being eliminated and, consequently, `u` is not pointing anywhere anymore
hence from the second iteration on, any attempt to access the variable `u` would lead to an error

while, if you use the `ws.Range(someaddress)`, you're always accessing the range of the currently `ws` worksheet with the same "local" address as that of `u`

Comment: This may fail after you delete the range corresponding to `u`. Probably requires storing `u.Address` in a variable first.

Comment: @BigBen, you're right. I just concentrated on the error solution 
Let's Shawn read your comment and put in place the proper adaptation